# Парсинг ссылок с помощью jsoup

Tags: jsoup, java, синтаксический-анализ

Коллеги, привет!
Я джуниор, изучаю jsoup и парсинг. Помогите, пожалуйста,понять, как со страницы отобрать ссылки, содержащие в названии "afisha". Тренируюсь на Yandex. Благодарю за помощь!
Вот код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc;
        try {
            //восстановление страницы html google
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yandex.ru/").get();
            String name = doc.title(); //извлекаем title страницы
            System.out.println("Name of page html: "+name);

            Elements urls = doc.select("a"); //парсим маяк "а"
            for(Element url : urls){ //перебираем все ссылки
                //... и вытаскиваем их название...
                System.out.println("\nhref Mayak <a> "+url.attr("href"));
//              System.out.println("\ntext Mayak <a> "+url.text());

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {           
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это было бы первое, что я попробовал:

    doc.select("a[name~=afisha]")

Comment: Смотри, у тебя есть переменная, которая содержит весь код страницы.
Тебе надо написать регулярное выражение по выборке ссылок, которые содержат в на звании "afisha".

Вот регулярка по выборке все url:

    /^(https?:\/\/)?([\w\.]+)\.([a-z]{2,6}\.?)(\/[\w\.]*)*\/?$/

Думаю, модернизировать данную регулярку под свои нужны тебе не составит труда. Удачи. :)

Comment: Вот более сложная:
~^(?:(?:https?|ftp|telnet)://(?:[a-z0-9_-]{1,32}(?::[a-z0-9_-]{1,32})?@)?)?(?:(?:[a-z0-9-]{1,128}\.)+(?:ru|su|com|net|org|mil|edu|arpa|gov|biz|info|aero|inc|name|[a-z]{2})|(?!0)(?:(?!0[^.]|255)[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}(?!0|255)[0-9]{1,3})(?:/[a-z0-9.,_@%&?+=\~/-]*)?(?:#[^ '\"&]*)?$~i

Comment: @МаринаВоин, человек использует более правильный способ. Регулярки конечно хороши, но в данном случае это не то, что нужно. 

Более того, эти регулярки не совсем верные. Они проверяют, что строка является адресом. А человеку нужно найти адрес в строке! Поэтому как минимум `^` и `$` в регулярке не нужны.

Также в второй регулярке можно половину выбросить, не потеряв функционала.

Comment: Прошу извинить, если мой коммент будет неверно истолкован. Среди полученных адресов ссылок мне необходимо выбрать только те, которые содержат afisha.

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, **никогда** не пользуйтесь регулярными выражениями для парсинга!

Во-вторых, работа с сетью производится **не** в главном потоке!

В-третьих, исправленный код:

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yandex.ru/").get();
    Element mBody = doc.body();
    String name = doc.title();
    System.out.println("Name of page html: " + name);

    Elements urls = body.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(Element url : urls)
    {
            //... и вытаскиваем их название...
            System.out.println("\nhref Mayak <a> "+url.attr("href"));

    }
} catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Comment: Коллеги, благодарю за ответы - буду пробовать.
Всем хорошего дня и только положительных мутаций :D

Comment: Коллеги, будет время, подскажите, пожалуйста. Я пока постараюсь дойти :)

Comment: Например, относительный URL на после вывода в консоли выглядит так:
href Mayak <a> https://afisha.yandex.ru/msk/events/1023133/
Он в числе тех, кто мне потребуется (есть afisha) :)

Comment: Коллеги, прошу, помогите, не получается понять, как решить поставленную задачу :(

Comment: +1, поставил бы ещё плюс за первые два пункта.